# Finding 4 unknown variables when given 3 equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The question has provided 
$$\begin{align}
        a+b+c+d&=402\\
        a+8&=d\\
        c+4&=b
\end{align}$$
    and that the largest and smallest integers are 2 less than the sum of the other two integers.

From these, I have managed to conclude that there are $6$ different pairs I need to find but I've only managed to find $4$.

$$\begin{align}
b+d&=207\\
a+c&=195\\
a+b&=199\\
c+d&=203
\end{align}$$

Am I going about things the right way? The end goal is to find what $a$,$b$,$c$, and $d$ are so I've done things in this way but I honestly can't figure out a way to figure out the last two pairs, which would be $a+d$ and $b+c$.

Answer (score 1):

The largest plus smallest is $200$ and the other two must add to $202$.

From the results you have already obtained,the largest and smallest must be $a$ and $d$. 
Then $d=a+8$ forces $a=96,d=104$. Then $b=103,c=99$.

Comment: While the answers do seem to work out when putting them back into the equations, isn't it possible that B could be larger than D?

Comment: From your results the largest and smallest would then be b and c. But they only differ by 4 and so don't have as big a spread as a and d.